# ng-repeat to open content

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to make a list of buttons appear, and once selected for the appropriate div underneath the button to be shown, I have used similar code before:

```
<li><button class="w3-button w3-grey w3-hover-dark-grey w3-round-xxlarge" ng-click="section = !section">Structure and function of the processor</button></li>
```

Which works fine so I am guessing it has something to do with $index

Do you have any idea how I could achieve this?

```
<div class="w3-panel" ng-show="section">
    henlo content
</div>

<div ng-app="tApp" ng-controller="tController">
    <ul class="w3-ul">
    <div ng-repeat="x in items">
        <li>
            <button class="w3-button w3-grey w3-hover-dark-grey w3-round-xxlarge" ng-click="section{{$index}} = !section{{$index}}">{{x.name}}</button>
        </li>
        <div class="w3-panel" ng-show="section{{$index}}">
            {{x.content}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
        var app=angular.module("tApp", []);
        app.controller("tController", function($scope)
        {
                $scope.items=[{name:"first",content:"henlo first"},{name:"second", content:"henlo second"}];
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can initialise a property with ng-init and use that property to show/hide content

```
<div ng-repeat="x in items" ng-init="x.displayContent = false">
    <li>
        <button class="w3-button w3-grey w3-hover-dark-grey w3-round-xxlarge" ng-click="x.displayContent = !x.displayContent">{{x.name}}</button>
    </li>
    <div class="w3-panel" ng-show="x.displayContent">
        {{x.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Am I right in thinking that 'displayContent' becomes an attribute of items?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. You are correct, it does.